# How to make a vectors unmodifiable when passing?

Tags: c++

My wording might not be correct, but I hope you'll understand what I mean.

Basically I have a `map<enum class, vector<struct*>>`. I want to pass the whole map without the vectors' contents being modifiable.
I need the structs as pointers, because I save references to some of them e.g. to the player instance and they'll get invalidated otherwhise.

It seems I can neither pass the map nor the vectors by reference. So this..

```
    std::map<myEnum, std::vector<const myStruct&>> getMap() {
        return myMap;
    }
```

..aswell as..

```
    const std::map<myEnum, std::vector<myStruct*>>& getMap() {
        return myMap;
    }
```

doesnt work.

Is there any way to solve this?

Sorry if the question is dumb, I'm kinda new to C++ and often don't know what to search for.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: "Basically I have a map<enum class, struct*>" ? Is it a `std::map<myEnum, std::vector<myStruct>>` ?

Comment: ok then there is a mismatch between `map<enum class, vector<struct*>>` and `std::map<myEnum, std::vector<myStruct>>`

Comment: Why not pass the map itself by `const` reference?   That prevents changing the map, as well as any of the vectors it maps to.

Comment: Do you mean the way proposed in the answer? At first I thought this would keep the contents of the vectors changeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should declare the member function itself `const`, otherwise it can't pick the member function for the `const` circumstance when the object itself is `const`.

Second, you don't have to think about the exact typing, you can let the compiler figure it out by saying `const auto&`. then it will return a constant reference, so it won't be modifiable:

```
const auto& GameLogic::getMap() const {
    return myMap;
}
```